# Problems targeting carriage return and newlines with regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, newline, carriage-return

I have some code that was working in isolation of a larger program, but now in the larger program it doesn't seem to be working--i.e. it is not performing the required actions.

The problem occurs at step 4 (see below) and, on reflection, my intended logic in the character class (i.e. 'everything except for a carriage return') doesn't seem to be correctly coded (but I don't know how else to 'phrase' the logic).

My aim is just to wrap each line or paragraph with paragraph tags.

Python Code

```
import re

# 1.  open the html file in read mode
html_file = open('test.html', 'r')

# 2.  convert to string
html_file_as_string = html_file.read()

# 3.  close the html file
html_file.close()

# 4.  replace carriage returns with closing and opening paragraph tags
html_file_as_string = re.sub('([^\r]*)\r', r'\1</p>\n<p>', html_file_as_string)

# 5.  remove time and date
html_file_as_string = re.sub(r'(Lorem ipsum \d*/\d*/\d*, \d*:\d* [a-z]{2})', r"", html_file_as_string)

# 6.  remove the white space after the opening paragraph tags
html_file_as_string = re.sub('<p>\n*\s*', r"<p>", html_file_as_string)

# 7.  remove the white space before the closing paragraph tags
html_file_as_string = re.sub('\s*</p>', r"</p>", html_file_as_string)

# 8.  open the file in write mode to clear
html_file = open('test.html', 'w')

# 9.  write the new contents to file
html_file.write(html_file_as_string)

# 10.  print to screen so we can see what is happening
print html_file_as_string

# 11.  close the html file
html_file.close()
```

Here is the contents of the HTML file:

```
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
   Lorem ipsum..consectetur adipiscing elit.
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", consectetur adipisc'ing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor...sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit..
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit..
   .....Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum 01/01/05, 05:00 am</p>
```

Here is the contents of the file viewed in the SciTE editor (so whitespace, carriage returns and new lines are visible).

[image]

**Edit:**

I changed the regex per the suggestions below and then doubled up of the substitution twice (changes from original code visible in step 4 and replication of step 6 before step 4).

Working Code:

```
import re

# 1.  open the html file in read mode
html_file = open('test.html', 'r')

# 2.  convert to string
html_file_as_string = html_file.read()

# 3.  close the html file
html_file.close()

# 6(added).  remove the white space after the opening paragraph tags
html_file_as_string = re.sub('<p>\n*\s*', r"<p>", html_file_as_string)

# 4(changed).  replace carriage returns with closing and opening paragraph tags
html_file_as_string = re.sub('([^\r\n]*)(\r\n?|\n)', r'\1</p>\2<p>', html_file_as_string)

# 5.  remove time and date
html_file_as_string = re.sub(r'(Lorem ipsum \d*/\d*/\d*, \d*:\d* [a-z]{2})', r"", html_file_as_string)

# 6.  remove the white space after the opening paragraph tags
html_file_as_string = re.sub('<p>\n*\s*', r"<p>", html_file_as_string)

# 7.  remove the white space before the closing paragraph tags
html_file_as_string = re.sub('\s*</p>', r"</p>", html_file_as_string)

# 8.  open the file in write mode to clear
html_file = open('test.html', 'w')

# 9.  write the new contents to file
html_file.write(html_file_as_string)

# 10.  print to screen so we can see what is happening
print html_file_as_string

# 11.  close the html file
html_file.close()
```

**Edit 2:**

The above code was too aggressive in other parts of the code and made too many modifications, back to the drawing board.

Comment: You have CRLF, which means `\r\n` ? Then you just need to make your regex more "universal". Try `([^\r\n]*)(\r\n?|\n)`, replacement `\1</p>\2<p>`

Comment: i'm just going to describe what i understand to be the logic of the pattern here, for myself and maybe others.  in group 1, 'everything except for carriage return or new line, repeated 0 or more times, and in group 2, 'carriage return followed by newline 0 or 1 times or just a new line, and the replacement of these groups is group 1, followed by `</p>` followed by group 2 followed by `<p>`.  i tried to run the above code and it looks good except the very first `<p>[CR][LF]` is turned into `<p></p>`.

Comment: Ok, I will propose (maybe a better) way to get this job done: **1-** Split/explode your text by `\r\n?|\n` **2-** Delete all empty elements from your array **3-** Append to the beginning of each element `<p>` and at the end `</p>`.

Comment: i didn't quite understand but i think made some changes based on this logic and have amended post above, the code appears to be working at this stage.

Comment: ergh, too aggressive in other parts of the code and makes too many modifications, back to the drawing board.

Comment: @HamZa : even better : `with open(html_file) as f: for line_with_returns in f: line = line_with_returns.rstrip('\r\n') (your code to insert the <p>s here)`

Comment: @bernardpaulus I don't code in python xD Just checking the regex tag :-)

Comment: @user1063287, some of the strings being used as regex above do not have the r (raw) prefix - add that in on each regex and replacement string and see if it helps.  What exactly is the problem?  Does it just fail to do step 4?  Does it give an error?  what error?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are better iterating through the string rather than trying to do stuff with regex as Python you can do this in a few steps

```
import re
parsed_html = []

# Open the file and close it after being read
with open('test.html', 'r') as html_file:
    lines = html_file.readlines()

# Iterate through each line using \r\n, \r or \n as separators 
for line in lines:
    # Remove whitespace chars before and after the content (6 & 7)
    line = line.strip()

    # Skip empty lines (you could merge this and latter if)
    if not line:
         continue

    # Skip lines with only <p> or </p> (check output and remove if not needed)
    if re.match("^</?p>$", line):
         continue

    # Remove the date line (using + instead of * as * matches 0 or more entries)
    line = re.sub(r'Lorem ipsum \d+/\d+/\d+, \d+:\d+ (am|pm)', '', line)

    # Make sure we add p tag and CL/LR to the end of each line
    line = "<p>{0}</p>\r\n".format(line)

    # Append current line to a list that we will use to write the file
    parsed_html.append(line)

# Write contents of the parsed html to the file
with open('test.html', 'w') as html_file:
    html_file.writelines(parsed_html)
```